# Binding the button Content to the userControl Content

Tags: wpf, binding

I have some userControl that contain simple button. 
I want to bind the button Content to the userControl Content - How to do it?

Comment: Do you want to bind Content property of a button to the content of a userControl that contains the button or am I reading your question incorrectly?

Comment: :) the other way .... content of the userControl to Content of the button ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set a name for the user control (for example `x:Name="self"`) and in the Button

```
<Button Content={Binding ElementName=self}" />
```

Do you mean this or something else?

Answer (score 2):

If the Button is inside the UserControl it is part of the UserControl's Content and can't recursively contain itself. The whole purpose of a UserControl is that you're explicitly defining a fixed set of Content. If you want variable Content then you should use a templated ContentControl something like this:

```
  <ContentControl Content="{Binding SomeVariableValue}">
    <ContentControl.Template>
      <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ContentControl}">
        <Border>
          <!-- Other content from your user control -->
          <Button Content="{TemplateBinding Content}"/>
        </Border>
      </ControlTemplate>
    </ContentControl.Template>
  </ContentControl>
```